netcat showing no response
I'm trying to trouble shoot why i could'nt mount my NAS to my coding envionment.
I try netcat command to check port 445: nc my_NAS_IP 445 and the command shows no response
Anyone has an idea of what's happening here ?
Thanks

Try with the options -zv according to man nc chapter 'PORT SCANNING'.
